# Handling Audio File Uploads in Nuxt 3 for Whisper API - BadRequestError

Tags: node.js, typescript, nuxt.js, openapi, openai-whisper

I am working on a project where the client-side needs to POST an audio file to the server route in Nuxt 3. From the server, this file is then sent to the Whisper API to get a transcription response. However, I am encountering a BadRequest error when the server attempts to process the audio file. I would appreciate any insights or solutions to this issue. My knowledge in this area is limited, so detailed guidance would be incredibly helpful.

Error Messages:
Client-side: Transcript: Internal Server Error
Server-side: BadRequestError: 400 Unrecognized file format. Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']

client:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const audioFile = ref(null)
const transcript: any = ref('')

onMounted(() => {
  watchEffect(() => {
    console.log('audioFile:', audioFile.value)
  })
})

const uploadAudio = async () => {
  if (!audioFile.value) {
    transcript.value = '音声ファイルが選択されていません‼️'
    return
  }else{
    transcript.value = ''
  }

  isLoading.value = true
  if (!audioFile.value) {
    console.error('No audio file selected')
    return
  }
  console.log('audioFile:', audioFile.value)
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('audio', audioFile.value)
  console.log(formData.get("audio"))

  try {
    const res = await $fetch('/api/whisper', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
    transcript.value = res.body
    console.log('Transcript:', transcript.value)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading audio:', error)
  }
  isLoading.value = false
}

//test関数
const testText: any = ref("")
const isLoading = ref(false)
const clickTest = ref(false)
const test = async () => {
  isLoading.value = true
  clickTest.value = true
  //postリクエストする意味はないが、fetchのテストとして使用
  const res = await $fetch('/api/test', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: { test: 'test' }
  })
  testText.value = res.body
  isLoading.value = false
}

//formで試してみる
const submit = async (event:any) => {
  event.preventDefault() // フォームのデフォルトの送信を防ぐ
  if (!audioFile.value) {
    console.error('No audio file selected')
    transcript.value = '音声ファイルが選択されていません‼️'
    return
  }

  isLoading.value = true
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('audio', audioFile.value)

  const res = await $fetch('/api/whisper', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })
  .then((res) => {
    transcript.value = res.body
    console.log('Transcript:', transcript.value)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error uploading audio:', error)
  })
  isLoading.value = false
}

</script>

<template>
  <div class="p-2">
    <!-- formで試してみる -->
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
      <input class="inline-block" type="file" @change="audioFile = $event.target.files[0]" accept="audio/*" />
      <input type="submit" value="Transcribe Audio" />
    </form>


    <UInput class="inline-block" type="file" @change="audioFile = $event.target.files[0]" accept="audio/*" color="primary" variant="outline" />
    <UButton @click="uploadAudio">Transcribe Audio</UButton>
    <UButton @click="test">test</UButton>
    <div v-if="isLoading">取得中です...(結構時間かかります)</div> 
    <!-- transcript -->
    <div v-if="transcript">Transcript: {{ transcript }}</div>


    <!-- testText -->
    <div>
      <div v-if="clickTest" class="text-xl font-bold">・要約</div>
      <div v-if="testText.abstractSummary">{{ testText.abstractSummary }}</div>

      <div v-if="clickTest" class="text-xl font-bold">・キーポイント</div>
      <div v-if="testText.keyPoints">{{ testText.keyPoints }}</div>

      <div v-if="clickTest" class="text-xl font-bold">・タスク</div>
      <div v-if="testText.actionItems">{{ testText.actionItems }}</div>

      <div v-if="clickTest" class="text-xl font-bold">・会議の様子</div>
      <div v-if="testText.sentiment">{{ testText.sentiment }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

sever:

```
import OpenAI from "openai";
import formidable from 'formidable';
import fs from 'fs';

const openAI = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
})

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    // const formData = await readBody(event)
    // console.log("formData:", formData)
    console.log("1")
    //ファイルの解析を行う関数の呼び出し
    const { fields, files } = await parseForm(event);
    console.log("fields:", files)
    console.log("2")
    const audioFile = files.audio
    console.log("3")
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // console.log("formData.audio:", formData.audio)
    // const audioFile = formData.audio
    if (!audioFile) throw new Error('Audio file is missing')
    console.log("audioFiles",audioFile[0].filepath)
    const filePath = audioFile[0].filepath
    if (!filePath) {
      console.error('ファイルパスが未定義です。')
      return
    }
    const transcript = await openAI.audio.transcriptions.create({
      model: "whisper-1", 
      file: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
      language: "ja"
    })

    return {
      status: 200,
      body: transcript
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return {
      status: 500,
      body: "Internal Server Error"
    }
  }
})

//ファイルの解析を行う関数
async function parseForm(event: any) {
  console.log("a")
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = formidable();
    console.log("b")
    form.parse(event.req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve({ fields, files })
      console.log("c")
    })
  })
}
```

console:

```
1
a
b
c
fields: {
  audio: [
    PersistentFile {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      lastModifiedDate: 2024-02-20T05:33:13.925Z,
      filepath: '/var/folders/8b/1nl0xyjj4gj6ssvbr3l0q8rr0000gq/T/b1420148798c105a084f2ab00',
      newFilename: 'b1420148798c105a084f2ab00',
      originalFilename: 'text.wav',
      mimetype: 'audio/wav',
      hashAlgorithm: false,
      size: 14040414,
      _writeStream: [WriteStream],
      hash: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  ]
}
2
3
audioFiles /var/folders/8b/1nl0xyjj4gj6ssvbr3l0q8rr0000gq/T/b1420148798c105a084f2ab00
BadRequestError: 400 Unrecognized file format. Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']
    at Function.generate (/Users/User2/Desktop/Desktop/voiceTransrate/node_modules/openai/src/error.ts:67:14)
    at OpenAI.makeStatusError (/Users/User2/Desktop/Desktop/voiceTransrate/node_modules/openai/src/core.ts:383:21)
    at OpenAI.makeRequest (/Users/User2/Desktop/Desktop/voiceTransrate/node_modules/openai/src/core.ts:446:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at <anonymous> (/Users/User2/Desktop/Desktop/voiceTransrate/server/api/whisper.post.ts:30:1)
    at async Object.handler (file:///Users/User2/Desktop/Desktop/voiceTransrate/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1697:19)
    at async Server.toNodeHandle (file:///Users/User2/Desktop/Desktop/voiceTransrate/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1907:7) {
  status: 400,
  headers: {
    'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400',
    'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
    'cf-ray': '85845f60fbdce025-NRT',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '231',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    date: 'Tue, 20 Feb 2024 05:33:07 GMT',
    'openai-organization': 'user-15mkr0kxmibnlowacyvlfabe',
    'openai-processing-ms': '235',
    'openai-version': '2020-10-01',
    server: 'cloudflare',
    'set-cookie': '__cf_bm=x0Ot5GEKGlzKpjKe6EPLlibIjmx4lbCvlUMKxVOzdnk-1708407187-1.0-AavVZeYDQn/+mcLEHR3eSNYVnLJ3ThdE5t/Ixn0fBAB4Fhe8Tq6w7bpR/NBnNwvjtkRozRHUh+4ybDtTtgEupJA=; path=/; expires=Tue, 20-Feb-24 06:03:07 GMT; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None, _cfuvid=6EiNSl7qMSDVq1cQG.oJILIVXezA_JunHU0lJKo8xQ4-1708407187423-0.0-604800000; path=/; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains',
    'x-ratelimit-limit-requests': '100',
    'x-ratelimit-remaining-requests': '99',
    'x-ratelimit-reset-requests': '600ms',
    'x-request-id': 'req_bdb2f53070eb57df88c963da5920259a'
  },
  error: {
    message: "Unrecognized file format. Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']",
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    param: null,
    code: null
  },
  code: null,
  param: null,
  type: 'invalid_request_error'
}
```

On the client-side, I've implemented a feature to select an audio file and POST it to my server using FormData.
On the server-side, I attempted to parse the incoming file using formidable and then send it to the Whisper API using openai SDK.
I expected the Whisper API to accept the audio file and return a transcription.
However, I receive a BadRequestError indicating an "Unrecognized file format," even though the file is a WAV format, which is supposed to be supported.